# How to make navbar background appear when scrolling down, but disappear when scrolled up

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So my background image in my first section goes behind the navbar and underneath it. So basically what I want, when I am scrolled to the top of the page, I want the background of the navbar to disappear, but not the list items in the nav bar. As soon as I scroll down, I would like for a background on the navbar to reappear. I believe this requires jquery, like an if/else statement, which I am not familiar with at all. Also, if I need to add jquery, do I need to add a CDN anywhere in my HTML? If so, where do I place it? If it makes any difference, I used bootstrap to make my navbar. I am only a few days into coding, I'm brand new. Here are my HTML and CSS

```html
    <style>
        .navbar-default {
            background-color: black !important;
            opacity: .6 !important;
            min-height:90px !important;
            border-radius: 5px !important;
            position: fixed; !important;
            width: 100%; !important;
            z-index: 100 !important;
        }
        .nav li {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
        .nav li a {
            color: white !important;
            font-size: 1.2em !important;
        }
        .navbar-brand {
            padding-right: 50px !important;
        } 
        .topInfo {
            background-image: url('/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/miami beach-1.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            height: 684px;
        }
        .topInfoText {
            color: white;
            padding-top: 220px;
        }
    </style>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    
    <section class="topInfo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class=" topInfoText text-center">Aerial Photography In South Florida</h1>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
    
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check that out, https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some jQuery to tell your navigation to add and remove a class if the user is or is not scrolled to the top:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos <= 0) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('top-of-page');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('top-of-page');
    }
});
```

Now with CSS change your background based on the new class being added and removed:

```
.navbar-default{background-color: black;}
.navbar-default.top-of-page{background-color: transparent;}
```

*Is there a reason why you are using so many !important tags in your example?*

EDIT: You may also find this helpful - http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/

Comment: Got a little carried away with the tags. I was overriding some of the bootstrap styles and ended up just putting it down on everything. I just went back and fixed those. Also, where do I place the jquery?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks

Comment: I am glad you were able to resolve the problem you were having.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with vanilla JavaScript, no need for JQuery if you don't want to add it. One way is to bind an event that adds/removes a class on your nav bar to the window scroll event, like so:

```
function toggleScrollClass() {
  var nav = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-default')[0];
  window.pageYOffset > 0 ? nav.classList.remove('fade') : nav.classList.add('fade')
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {toggleScrollClass()});
toggleScrollClass();
```

And then just create a .fade class in your CSS to do something different with the background:

```
.navbar-default.fade {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

You could even add some CSS transition/animation effect to the nav bar so you get a nice transition effect instead of a jump. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXyNNe